# Recycler view item animation on long press

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I need to clip all the items by a rounded rectangle shape in the recyclerview on long press, and display two views in the two extremes of each item view to select and rearrange the items. How to achieve this?
I am using Paging 3 library with RemoteMediator backed by roomdb for displaying the items.

On Long press:

1. Animate Translate all items to left ->
2. Animate a shape mask(Not scale the items but apply a rounded rectangular shape mask(or clip) to reveal less) and apply a gradient overlay to show the edit mode
3. Animate appearance(revealing) of two views in either sides of each item view
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I ended up creating inividual Animator objects and play them together using a AnimatorSet.

The RecyclerViewItemAnimatorSet class to fetch all the viewholders and apply animators recieved in its constructor

```kotlin
import android.animation.Animator
import android.animation.AnimatorSet
import androidx.core.animation.doOnEnd
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import timber.log.Timber
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

/**
 * @author sundara.santhanam
 * @since 09-09-2021
 */
class RecyclerViewItemAnimatorSet<in VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
    private val recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    private val animatorProviders: List<AnimatorProvider<VH>>,
    private val duration: Long,
    private val afterAnim: (SelectionModeAnimationState) -> Unit
) {
    private val forwardPlayInProgress = AtomicBoolean(false)
    private val reversePlayInProgress = AtomicBoolean(false)


    fun playTogether() {
        if (reversePlayInProgress.get().not()) {
            forwardPlayInProgress.set(true)
            playAnimation({ viewHolder ->
                animatorProviders.map { it.getForwardAnimator(viewHolder as VH) }
            }) {
                forwardPlayInProgress.set(false)
                theEnd(true)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun theEnd(selectionMode: Boolean) {
        var selectionModeAnimationState = SelectionModeAnimationState(selectionMode = selectionMode)
        animatorProviders.forEach {
            selectionModeAnimationState = it.mutateWithFinalValue(selectionModeAnimationState)
        }
        Timber.d("SelectionModeAnimationState: %s", selectionModeAnimationState)
        afterAnim(selectionModeAnimationState)
    }

    fun reversePlayTogether() {
        if (forwardPlayInProgress.get().not()) {
            reversePlayInProgress.set(true)
            playAnimation({ viewHolder -> animatorProviders.map { it.getReverseAnimator(viewHolder as VH) } }) {
                reversePlayInProgress.set(false)
                theEnd(false)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun playAnimation(
        animatorFetcher: (RecyclerView.ViewHolder) -> List<Animator>,
        performAtEnd: () -> Unit
    ) {
        for (index in recyclerView.visibleRange()) {
            recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(index)?.let { viewHolder ->
                val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
                animatorSet.playTogether(animatorFetcher(viewHolder))
                animatorSet.duration = duration
                animatorSet.start()
                animatorSet.doOnEnd {
                    performAtEnd.invoke()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AnimatorProvider contract:

```kotlin
/**
 * @author sundara.santhanam
 * @since 09-09-2021
 */
abstract class AnimatorProvider<in VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private var prevMode = 0
    fun getForwardAnimator(viewHolder: VH): Animator {
        val mode = 1
        if (prevMode != mode) {
            prevMode = mode
            onModeChange(mode, viewHolder)
        }
        return getAnimator(viewHolder, mode)
    }

    fun getReverseAnimator(viewHolder: VH): Animator {
        val mode = -1
        if (prevMode != mode) {
            prevMode = mode
            onModeChange(mode, viewHolder)
        }
        return getAnimator(viewHolder, mode)
    }

    abstract fun mutateWithFinalValue(selectionModeAnimationState: SelectionModeAnimationState): SelectionModeAnimationState
    val defaultValueAnimator: ValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f)

    // @param mode =1 is forward animation mode and -1 is reverse animation mode
    abstract fun onModeChange(
        mode: Int,
        viewHolder: VH
    )

    abstract fun getAnimator(viewHolder: VH, mode: Int): Animator
}
```

Example of an animator provider: OutlineProvider animator

```
/**
 * @author sundara.santhanam
 * @since 09-09-2021
 */
class OutLineAnimatorProvider : AnimatorProvider<FavoritesViewDelegate.FavViewHolder>() {
    private var finalRight: Int = -1
    private var initRight: Int = -1
    private var initHeight: Int = -1
    private var diff = 0f

    override fun getAnimator(
        viewHolder: FavoritesViewDelegate.FavViewHolder,
        mode: Int
    ): Animator {
        Timber.d(
            "%s initRight:%d finalRight:%s", (if (mode == 1) {
                "reverse"
            } else {
                "forward"
            }), initRight, finalRight
        )
        defaultValueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
            viewHolder.binding.itemContainer.updateRoundedCornersOutlineProvider(
                (initRight - mode * diff * (it.animatedValue as Float)).toInt(), initHeight
            )
            viewHolder.binding.itemContainer.requestLayout()
        }
        return defaultValueAnimator
    }

    override fun onModeChange(
        mode: Int,
        viewHolder: FavoritesViewDelegate.FavViewHolder
    ) {
        val prevInit = initRight
        initRight = if (finalRight == -1) {
            val bounds = Rect()
            viewHolder.binding.itemContainer.getDrawingRect(bounds)
            initHeight = bounds.height()
            diff = bounds.width() * FINAL_RIGHT_FACTOR
            Timber.d("initRight=%d width=%d diff=%f", bounds.right, bounds.width(), diff)
            bounds.right
        } else {
            finalRight
        }
        finalRight =
            if (prevInit != -1) {
                prevInit
            } else {
                (initRight - mode * diff).toInt()
            }
    }

    override fun mutateWithFinalValue(selectionModeAnimationState: SelectionModeAnimationState) =
        selectionModeAnimationState.copy(
            finalWidth = finalRight,
            initHeight = initHeight
        )

    companion object {
        const val FINAL_RIGHT_FACTOR = 0.2f
    }
}
```

The Rounded corner outline provider:

```kotlin
/**
 * @author sundara.santhanam
 * @since 09-09-2021
 */
data class RoundedCornersOutlineProvider(
    val radius: Float? = null,
    val width: Int? = null,
    val height: Int? = null
) : ViewOutlineProvider() {

    override fun getOutline(view: View, outline: Outline) {
        val left = 0
        val top = 0
        val right = width ?: view.width
        val bottom = height ?: view.height

        if (radius != null) {
            val cornerRadius = radius
            outline.setRoundRect(left, top, right, bottom, cornerRadius)
        }
    }
}

fun View.updateRoundedCornersOutlineProvider(width: Int, height: Int) {

    outlineProvider = try {
        (outlineProvider as RoundedCornersOutlineProvider).copy(
            width = width,
            height = height
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        RoundedCornersOutlineProvider(
            width = width,
            height = height
        )
    }
}

fun View.setRoundedCornerOutlineProvider(radiusDp: Float) {
    Utils.init(context)
    val radius = convertDpToPixel(radiusDp)
    val bounds = Rect()
    getDrawingRect(bounds)
    outlineProvider =
        RoundedCornersOutlineProvider(radius)
    clipToOutline = true
}

fun View.getOutlineRight(): Int {
    val bounds = Rect()
    getDrawingRect(bounds)
    return bounds.right
}
```

Usage in the recyclerview:

```kotlin
    private fun setupRecyclerView() {
        favoriteViewAnimatorSet = RecyclerViewItemAnimatorSet(
            binding.rvWishList, listOf(
                OutLineAnimatorProvider(),
                TranslationAnimatorProvider(),
                AlphaAnimatorProvider()
            ), 500L
        ) { selectionMode ->
            favoritesViewDelegate.selectionModeAnimationState.set(selectionMode)
            binding.rvWishList.adapter?.run {
                repeat(itemCount) { index ->
                    if (index !in binding.rvWishList.visibleRange()) {
                        notifyItemChanged(index)
                                            }
                }
            }
            binding.rvWishList.enableScroll(recyclerTouchDisabler, recyclerTouchListener)
        }
        binding.rvWishList.adapter =
            FavoritesAdapter(getListOfDelegates())
        recyclerTouchListener = RecyclerTouchListener(
            context, binding.rvWishList,
            clickListener = object : ClickListener {
                override fun onClick(view: View?, position: Int) {
                }

                override fun onLongClick(view: View?, position: Int) {
                    favoritesViewDelegate.selectionModeAnimationState.set(
                        selectionMode().copy(
                            selectionMode = !selectionMode().selectionMode
                        )
                    )
                    if (selectionMode().selectionMode) {
                        recyclerTouchDisabler =
                            binding.rvWishList.disableScrollAndGetDisabler(recyclerTouchListener)
                        favoriteViewAnimatorSet.playTogether()
                    } else {
                        recyclerTouchDisabler =
                            binding.rvWishList.disableScrollAndGetDisabler(recyclerTouchListener)
                        favoriteViewAnimatorSet.reversePlayTogether()
                    }
                }
            })

        binding.rvWishList.addOnItemTouchListener(recyclerTouchListener)
    }
```